# Возникает ошибка с python / vk_api (Import "vk_api" could not be resolved)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Через командную строку установил vk_api. Питон же не видит ничего. Почему такое может быть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно новичок, но вижу, что в VSC у тебя включен venv - виртуальное окружение, установи vk_api через терминал VSC.